# Solidity Uniswap: get token price

Tags: solidity

I am trying to get the price of a pair on UniswapV2:
This is my code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;

import '@uniswap/v2-core/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Pair.sol';
import './IERC20.sol';


contract Uniswap {

   // calculate price based on pair reserves
   function getTokenPrice(address pairAddress, uint amount) public view returns(uint)
   {
    IUniswapV2Pair pair = IUniswapV2Pair(pairAddress);
    IERC20 token1 = IERC20(pair.token1);
    (uint Res0, uint Res1,) = pair.getReserves();

    // decimals
    uint res0 = Res0*(10**token1.decimals());
    return((amount*res0)/Res1); // return amount of token0 needed to buy token1
   }
    
}
```

I manually imported the openzeppelin IERC20 interface and put as compiler version 0.5.1, because the current version of uniswap v2 periphery is 0.5.1

But I have the following error for the line `IERC20 token1 = IERC20(pair.token1);`:

```
Explicit type conversion not allowed from "function () view external returns (address)" to "contract IERC20". IERC20 token1 = IERC20(pair.token1); ^-----------------^
```

Any idea on how to solve that? thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are still looking for an answer for the decimal issue its becauses you need to use pair.decimals() not token1.decimals()

Comment: Actually using `pair.decimals()` is wrong because that is the decimal of the pair and has nothing to do with your calculation , this calculation will work only if all the tokens involved have 18 decimals , the error the op is facing is that he is using pair.token1 which is a function as a property so he should use `IERC20 token1 = IERC20(pair.token1);`

Answer (score 2):

The IUniswapV2Pair interface [defines](https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-core/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Pair.sol#L39) a `token1()` function - not `token1` property.

Their [contract](https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-core/blob/master/contracts/UniswapV2Pair.sol) then uses the fact, that signature of the property is the same as signature of the function, so that it doesn't need to implement the function (as long as it has the public property with the same name).

But when an external contract (such as yours) uses the interface to call functions, it needs to follow it exactly.

---

So you can simply replace

```
IERC20 token1 = IERC20(pair.token1); // original code
```

to

```
IERC20 token1 = IERC20(pair.token1()); // function `token1()`
```

Comment: That fixed it but now getting the error:
TypeErrorL Member "decimals" not found or not visible after argument

Comment: @user2324723 This doesn't seem like it's related to the original question or to this answer. Please [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) a separate question with steps to reproduce your issue... Based on the error message, I'm just guessing that you're trying to call the `decimals()` function on an `address` type instead of on the `IERC20` or `IUniswapV2Pair` instance.